# How to show a view in a datagrid?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

My doubt is simple. I'm creating a query using LINQ to ENTITIES.

I want to expose a property where returns the query.

I.E.

```
public ... GetScores
{
    get { from e in Exams
          select new { .. }
}
```

I do this to show the data in a datagrid and a graphic. But the problem is I need to especify the datatype like IEnumerable, so at this case T is an class where is anonymous.

Is necessary that I create a class where contains the properties of the query?

Real example

```
            List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>()
            {
                new Student() { Name="Oscar", ExamResults = new List<float>() {0.8f, 0.75f, 0.6f, 0.95f }},
                new Student() { Name="Juan", ExamResults = new List<float>() {0.4f, 0.6f, 0.7f }},

            };

            var query = from s in studentList
                        select new
                        {
                            Name = s.Name,
                            Avg = s.ExamResults.Average(),
                            Description = string.Format("{0} of {1} accredited.", s.ExamResults.Count(e => e > 0.7f), s.ExamResults.Count)
                        };

public class Student
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<float> ExamResults { get; set;}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
public IEnumerable<Object> Query { get { return query; } }
```